# How to use tf.train.batch with enqueue_many=true

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looking for an example of using `tf.train.batch` with `enqueue_many=True`.

In my case, I have an image tensor of shape [299,299,3] and when I call a function `get_distortions(image)` it will return a new tensor of shape [10,299,299,3] (in this example, it will apply 10 distortions to the image and return them all as a new tensor). I'd then like to enqueue all these by calling `tf.train.batch`.

I tried this:

```
example_batch = tf.train.batch(tf.unpack(distortions), 5, enqueue_many=True)
```

But when I `sess.run(example_batch)` I get back a list of length 10 (I was expecting a batch of size 5).

Also, how would I include the label to `tf.train.batch` in this case? The label is the same for all 10 distortions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't unpack `distortions`.  The semantics of `enqueue_many` is that you feed it a tensor with first dimension being the batching dimension, so a `[10, 299, 299, 3]` tensor with enqueue_many will result in ten separate items, each of shape `299, 299, 3` being enqueued -- which is what you want.

Comment: Without unpacking Im getting this error: `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable`

Comment: Got this working by doing `tf.train.batch([distortions])`. Just had to wrap the tensor in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) tells you:

> If enqueue_many is True, tensors is assumed to represent a batch of
>   examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example, and all
>   members of tensors should have the same size in the first dimension.
>   If an input tensor has shape [*, x, y, z], the output will have shape
>   [batch_size, x, y, z]. The capacity argument controls the how long the
>   prefetching is allowed to grow the queues.

Which is exactly what happens in your case: `[10, 299, 299, 3]`, where 10 is the batch size. So you do not need to do any unpacking and `tf.train.batch(distortions, 5, enqueue_many=True)` will do the job.